# How to estimate the settling time of the rotor of a stepper motor?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

I'm trying to estimate how long I need my stepper's pulses to be to ensure I don't miss steps and assess how big the vibrations will be because of the ringing (i.e. how fast it can be, considering a fixed end-of-step precision requirement).

I've tried to start from:
$$\tau=J\frac{d²\theta}{dt²}$$
Where J is the total inertia (with load).

However, I think that for one step, the torque is $$\tau=cos(\theta)$$
And I don't know how to solve that... I can't take the small angles approximation, otherwise it never stabilizes.

Then how? I've looked everywhere for the equation of the time history of the position of the rotor for a single step, but never managed to find it. That's kind of the fundamentals though, right?

Comment: settling time will also depend on the mechanical time constant of the system, which includes the load.

Comment: If you want to ensure, you need feedback. Otherwise you can only hope. Which is why in any system that requires minimum reliability servo motor (even with dc brushed or stepper motor) is more adequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tau=J\frac{d²\Theta}{dt²}+F\frac{d\Theta}{dt}+\tau_L$$ 
$$\tau-\tau_L=J\frac{d\Omega}{dt}+F\Omega$$ 
$$\dot{\Omega} + \frac{F}{J}\Omega=\frac{\tau_L-\tau}J$$

Solve the differential equation, \$\Omega\propto pulses/s\$

edit:
$$\frac{d²\Theta}{dt²}+\frac{F}{J}\cdot\frac{d\Theta}{dt}+\frac{\tau_L-\tau_nsin(\Theta_{el})}{J}=0$$ \$\Theta_{el}=\dfrac{4\Theta}{fullsetps}\$ ; you can substitute \$\Theta\$

Inital condition: \${\tau_L-\tau_nsin(\Theta_{el_{initial}})}=0\$ , in absence of load torque, the electic angle \$\Theta_{el_{initial}}\$ is zero, since no output torque is produced. This also means that rotor flux is alligned with stator flux.

At time t=0, the stator winding is switched so that \$\Theta_{el}=\Theta_{el_{initial}} + \dfrac{\pi}{2}\$, the stator flux is at 90deg in relation with rotor flux (if we ommit the static load torque, that brings the rotor at initial position different than 0deg )

Comment: Except that tau is not constant, it depends on the angle of the rotor - that's the reason why the rotor settles at a specific position for a given energized coil.

Comment: \$T=\Psi_R*I_q=T_{max}sin(\Theta_{el})\$ The torque is maximal between two positions, if the rotor lags the stator field by 90degrees then you get a nominal torque, at standstill this torque is zero if no external torque is applied. But you can ommit this nature of torque, since the rotor will always lag when accelerating.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, basically I want to plot the position of the rotor during one step to see the oscillation settle.. If you replace omega by dtheta/dt and tau by Tmsin(theta), then it would go in the right direction but I've tried that and I can't solve it

Comment: @user42875 I have edited the formula, now it's 2nd order differential equation. I am little out of this kind of math, but you can ask in math forum which analytical solution comes out- think it's Euler ODE.

Comment: The system is NOT second order...it's  a fourth-order non-linear system.  Your best bet would be to run a computer simulation of the single-step response.  The motor inductance and resistance have an effect on the settling time!

Answer (score 0):

You can run a computer simulation that is reasonably accurate with the following equations.....
$$
\dot i_a = \frac{1}{L}(v_a-Ri_a+K_E\omega_msin(N_R\theta_m))
$$
$$
\dot i_b = \frac{1}{L}(v_b-Ri_b-K_E\omega_mcos(N_R\theta_m))
$$
$$
\dot \omega_m=\frac{1}{J}(-K_Ti_asin(N_R\theta_m)+K_Ti_bcos(N_R\theta_m)-B\omega_m)
$$
$$
\dot \theta_m = \omega_m
$$
Where the state variables are:
$$
i_a=  current\ in\ phase\ a
$$
$$
i_b= current \ in \ phase\ b
$$
$$
\omega_m= rotor \ angular \ velocity
$$
$$
\theta_m = rotor \ angle
$$
with the following constants:
$$
R = \ winding \ resistance
$$
$$
L = \  winding \ inductance
$$
$$
K_T = \ torque \ constant
$$
$$
K_E = \ Back \ EMF \ constant
$$
$$
J = \ rotor \ inertia
$$
$$
N_R = \ number \ of \ rotor \ teeth
$$
$$
B = \ viscous \ friction
$$
and the following inputs:
$$
v_a = \ voltage \ applied \ to \ phase \ a
$$
$$
v_b = \ voltage \ applied \ to \ phase \ b
$$
For a 200 step/revolution hybrid step motor,
$$
N_R = 50.
$$
Any simulation software should work just fine, as long as
the time step is small enough.